# Matlab - clever rename files and references

Tags: matlab, rename

Suppose I have following script files:

- a.m, b.m, c.m,
- ABC.m

and ABC is referencing to scripts a.m, b.m, c.m in its code.

Is there any clever way to renaming a.m, b.m, c.m and their names in code in ABC.m, instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [automatic renaming](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2011/09/12/variable-and-function-rename/) provided by the built-in editor that was introduced in R2011b. [More documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-and-replace-text-in-files.html#bs22l6l). Note that this only changes the occurances of calls to `a`, `b`, and `c` in the file `ABC.m`. You will need to update all necessary files and also change the *filenames* of `a.m`, `b.m`, and `c.m` manually.

You can start to rename a variable in the editor and there should be a pop-up that will allow you to rename all occurrences using **shift+enter**.

[image]

You could potentially find all affected files using the [file search](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/finding-files-and-folders.html), however variable names such as `a` are so non-specific that you're going to get a lot of false positives. Hopefully you've named your functions/scripts something a little more descriptive.

So in short, clever? No. Semi-automatic? Barely.

Comment: This can rename all occurences in file ABC, but you still need to rename files a, b and c separately.

Comment: Yes I have used more descriptive names :)
I also have used Shift+Enter to rename :)
But good point here about proper order of renaming - variables first, files second.